# Passing two variables in route through javascript function in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes

I am trying to send two variables in route through java script function.
Javascript function:

```
function bookmark()
{       
     var url = '{{ route("save_bookmark",":b_id",":p_no") }}';       
      url = url.replace(':b_id', book);
      url = url.replace(':p_no', count);
     document.location.href = url;

}
```

book and count variables have been defined up in script.

When I pass only one variable through this code, it works fine but when I try to pass another variable it gives me error..

> Missing required parameters for [Route: save_bookmark] [URI:save_bookmark/{b_id}/{p_no}].

My route:

```
Route::get("save_bookmark/{b_id}/{p_no}",'BookmarkController@create')->name('save_bookmark');
```

Do anyone know what's happening?

Comment: your `blade` template is going to render and execute the route before your javascript even replaces the variables.

Comment: So what is proper way then?

Comment: `route('save_bookmark', ['b_id' => ':b_id', 'p_no' => ':p_no'])` [Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route)

Comment: This worked!! Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can still do it this way!

javascript

```
function bookmark()
{       
     var url = '{{ route("save_bookmark",":b_id",":p_no") }}';       
      url1 = url.replace(':b_id', book);
      url2 = url.replace(':p_no', count);
     //document.location.href = url;
     document.href="https://example.com/save_bookmark/"+url1 +"/"+url2;
      or
     location.href="https://example.com/save_bookmark/"+url1 +"/"+url2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Looks Good:
try it =>**

```
let val1= "1122";
let val2= "a1b2c3";
    var processUrl = '{{ url("/path/:param1/:param2") }}';
        processUrl = processUrl.replace(':param1', val1);
        processUrl = processUrl.replace(':param2', val2);
    document.location.href = processUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Works for me**

```
function bookmark()
{
  var book = 1; var count = 2;
  var url = '{{ route("save_bookmark",[":b_id",":p_no"]) }}';
  url = url.replace(':b_id', book);
  url = url.replace(':p_no', count);
  console.log(url);
}
```