# laravel route helper parameter with JavaScript

Tags: laravel

laravel route helper parameter with JavaScript
There is a problem.

```
<script>
    let url = "<a href='{{ route('admin.user.update', ["+ row.idx +"]) }}' class='link-success'>"
</script>
```

result
https://example.com/user/update/+%20row.idx%20+

Result value I want
https://example.com/user/update/1023223

Comment: Is that inside a blade view? Then use blade syntax to get the result. What does `left url` do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56430916/7964905 check this answer

Comment: You try to mix php (blade) and javascript. The php is server side, javascript client side. you can output the url, and change it with javascript, but you can't expect blade to use js vars.

Comment: Please share your route

Comment: @brombeer Modified to "let".  inside the blade template (blade.php)

Comment: @A.ANoman inside the blade template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let url = "<a href='{{ route("admin.user.update/'+ row.idx +'")]) }}' class='link-success'></a>"</script>
```

Comment: Still uses javascript and blade mixed, this can not work. How does this answer get accepted? And the route syntax is wrong. It's a named route, so the `/` does not belong there. This will throw a "route not defined" error

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 let url = '<a href="{{ route("admin.user.update/'+ row.idx +'") }}" class="link-success"></a>'</script>

Comment: No, you can not use `+ row.idx +` in `{{ route() }}` and the route name is `admin.user.update`. This might work depending on the route file:  `href="{{ route("admin.user.update") }}/'+ row.idx +'"`

Comment: There is an [edit] link below your answer post. Please use that to update your post.